How can I resolve a lifetime error with an async FnOnce call
I'm trying to create a transaction Unit Of Work implementation and am getting a "lifetime may not live long enough returning this value requires that '1 must outlive '2" error en the .execute method in main. Ideas on where the issue is?
Full error:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:78:23
   |
78 |           .execute(|tx| async {
   |  ___________________---_^
   | |                   | |
   | |                   | return type of closure `{async block@src/main.rs:78:23: 82:10}` contains a lifetime `'2`
   | |                   has type `&'1 mut DatabaseTransaction`
79 | |             UserRepository::create_user(tx, "test_user").await?;
80 | |             OrderRepository::create_order(tx, 1, "test_product").await?;
81 | |             Ok::<(), Error>(())
82 | |         })
   | |_________^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`


Code
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error)]
pub enum Error {
    #[error(transparent)]
    Any(#[from] Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>),
}

struct DatabaseConnection {}

impl DatabaseConnection {
    async fn begin(&self) -> Result<DatabaseTransaction, Error> {
        Ok(DatabaseTransaction {})
    }
}

struct DatabaseTransaction {}

impl DatabaseTransaction {
    async fn commit(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub struct UnitOfWork<'a> {
    pool: &'a DatabaseConnection,
}

impl<'a> UnitOfWork<'a> {
    pub fn new(pool: &'a DatabaseConnection) -> Self {
        UnitOfWork { pool }
    }

    pub async fn execute<F, T>(&self, operation: F) -> Result<T, Error>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut DatabaseTransaction) -> T + Send,
        T: Send,
    {
        let mut tx = self.pool.begin().await?;

        // Execute the operation within the transaction
        let result = operation(&mut tx);

        // Commit or rollback based on the operation result
        tx.commit().await?;

        Ok(result)
    }
}

pub struct UserRepository;

impl UserRepository {
    pub async fn create_user(tx: &mut DatabaseTransaction, username: &str) -> Result<(), Error>  {
        Ok(())
    }

    pub async fn delete_user(tx: &mut DatabaseTransaction, user_id: i32) -> Result<(), Error> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub struct OrderRepository;

impl OrderRepository {
    pub async fn create_order(
        tx: &mut DatabaseTransaction,
        user_id: i32,
        product_name: &str,
    ) -> Result<(), Error> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let pool = DatabaseConnection {};
    let uow = UnitOfWork::new(&pool);
    let result = uow
        // lifetime error here
        .execute(|tx| async {
            UserRepository::create_user(tx, "test_user").await?;
            OrderRepository::create_order(tx, 1, "test_product").await?;
            Ok::<(), Error>(())
        })
        .await;

    match result {
        Ok(_) => println!("Transaction succeeded!"),
        Err(err) => println!("Transaction failed: {:?}", err),
    }

    Ok(())
}

I'm expecting the tx to be available to the async block to execute multiple database calls in the same transaction

You will need to take an async function. The easiest way is to take impl Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future>>.
